# Google Cloud Function/NodeJS - Parse int from JSON form event

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

How I can parse int from JSON which I get from Cloud Pub/Sub? I tried many ways but no one was successful. Here is my example code and output from it.

```
exports.subscribe = (event, callback) => {
  const pubsubMessage = event.data;

  console.log(Buffer.from(pubsubMessage.data, 'base64').toString());
  console.log(pubsubMessage.temp);

  callback();
};
```

[image: Consol logs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(pubsubMessage.data, 'base64').toString());
console.log(obj.temp);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying something similiar but I dont know why it was fail.